# Java- Insert records in batch does not work in MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql

So I have created a simple program to insert rows to my database(MYSQL) table. I am inserting the records in a batch of 1,000. It works perfectly fine but as is it inserting the 1st batch of 1,000 before completion, I am still able to check the records in my table and there exists records (<1000).

I thought inserting by batch means the behavior should be after the 1st 1000 records completed, then it starts populate the table and if I check the table before it completes the 1st batch, it should return an empty table. That's how I believe it should work.

Code(snippet):

```
for (int i=1; i < words.length; i++) {
    preparedStatement.setString(1, path);
    preparedStatement.setString(2, words[i]);
    preparedStatement.addBatch();
    if (i % 1000 == 0) {
        preparedStatement.executeBatch();
        System.out.print("Add Thousand");
    }
}

if (words.length % 1000 > 0) {
    preparedStatement.executeBatch();
    System.out.print("Add Remaining");
}
```

Is this how the nature of MySQL behaves even though it is inserting in batches but it `"appears"` to be inserting row by row as it begins the batch?

Shouldn't the table appear empty until the first batch of 1000 has been executed?

Can anyone explain what is going on?

Comment: I'm not an expert here, but I _think_ what is happening is that when you query it is in the middle of a batch, and you are just seeing some fraction of the first 1000 records having already been inserted.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen So it is still inserting in batches  but it does not appear so in the table if i try to search for records?

Comment: I'm not sure that MySQL even has any knowledge of what a "batch" is.  It might just be a JDBC thing, which lets you build a series of inserts, which then all get inserted at once at some later point.

Comment: I see but I have seen a big improve in performance when inserting in the batch, just that the behavior of populating the db confuses me.

Comment: Well, if it can do all those inserts with the same connection, at the same time, that should outperform just doing separate inserts a la carte.

Comment: In that case, the for loop and if statement won't even be neccessary if it's not inserting in batches as what you said.

Comment: The alternative to what you are doing would be to open a separate connection for each insert.  This is very wasteful, because you might as well do many inserts together, using the same connection.  This is the point of batches AFAIK.